# TFS 2015 Web Access export to Excel

Tags: tfs, excel-2013, tfs-2015, tfs-web-access

As mentioned in the title, is there a way from the web access of TFS 2015 to open a particular query in MS Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the Workaround with Team Explorer Everywhere as mentioned [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4152668-export-to-excel-from-team-web-access-for-tfs-2012).

Still waiting for this feature in TFS 2015.

Comment: You can also check this MSDN article for the details on how to manage work items in Excel: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286627.aspx

Comment: You must be administrator to install this. I am just a user, who opens the browser. There should be a browser plugin that downloads the data shown on screen.